# Service crashes on 'death' of Activity

Tags: android, service, crash

I have an Activity that starts a Service.

In my Activity:

```
startService(new Intent(this, MyService.class));
```

In my Service, onStart():

```
/* Show notification */
int icon = R.drawable.icon;
tickerText = getResources().getString(R.string.app_name);
long when = System.currentTimeMillis();
contentTitle = getResources().getString(R.string.app_name);
contentText = getResources().getString(R.string.running);

Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, activityClass).setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN).setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, 0);
notification = new Notification(icon, tickerText, when);
notification.setLatestEventInfo(this, contentTitle, contentText, contentIntent);

notification.flags = Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT;

((NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE)).notify(0, notification);

startForeground(0, notification);
```

The service has a timer that does some work every 3-4 minutes, and broadcasts info to the Activity if possible. When the Activity is closed, the Service should keep doing its work.

When I run the app, and go back to the homescreen, the Service keeps running. But after a while I get these logcat messages, and the service stops:

> 07-03 16:55:09.440: INFO/ActivityManager(583): Process com.myapp (pid 11665) has died.
>   07-03 16:55:09.440: WARN/ActivityManager(583): Scheduling restart of crashed service com.myapp/.MyService in 5000ms

How can I prevent this?

Comment: Okay, and how to prevent the process from dying?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When I run the app, and go back to the homescreen, the Service keeps running. But after a while I get these logcat messages, and the service stops... How can I prevent this?

You don't, generally speaking.

Services are not designed to run forever. Too many developers have started services and never stopped them. And, in your case, they do so for no good reason. Having a service hang around in memory just watching the clock tick is wasteful, and it is particularly because developers do things like this that Android "crashes" services after they stick around too long.

In your case, please switch to use `AlarmManager`, probably in conjunction with an `IntentService`, so the service shuts down on its own accord when there is no more work to be done.

Comment: I tried to use the AlarmManager, but preferred a workaround if possible, because I'm using analytics. These are started and closed with a context, that must be the same. When I close the service, the context is lost, and I cannot close the analytics instance. Or is there another way to do this? (I'm using Flurry by the way).

Comment: @Niek: "Or is there another way to do this?" -- track usage data yourself. Or switch to another analytics package, one designed to work with services.

Answer (score 7):

The provided answers didn't help me. But I found a really easy way to do this, add in the Manifest

```
    <service android:name="..." android:process=":remote" />
```

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/service-element.html

Just testing at the moment, my Activity got already killed, but my service is running.

Answer (score 1):

You will want to look at having your service run as a `Remote Service`, so that it runs in its own process.

A blog about remote services:
http://saigeethamn.blogspot.com/2009/09/android-developer-tutorial-part-9.html

An example of a sample one:
http://about-android.blogspot.com/2010/02/android-remote-service-sample.html

Comment: This will mean the app takes up twice the RAM while the activity is around, which takes a wasteful app and makes it worse.

Comment: @CommonsWare - The Activity may not need to run all the time, but, regardless, if the application needs to work, and it stops because the Activity is ended, then some solution needs to be found.

Comment: @James Black: Services are always meant to be shut down, ideally by the developer, then by the user (task killer, Settings app, etc.), then by the OS (what's happening in this case). Any application design that assumes that a service will live forever is fundamentally flawed. Furthermore, "remote services" in this fashion are no more immune to being stopped by users or the OS than is a local service.

Comment: @CommonsWare - But the death of the Activity will not kill a remote service. That was the problem that the OP is having, so the only way I can see to deal with it was remote services. Without knowing what the application is for, whether a long-running service is needed is guesswork.

Comment: @James Black: "That was the problem that the OP is having" -- no, it's not, despite the OP's title. Quoting the last paragraph, "When I run the app, and go back to the homescreen, the Service keeps running. But after a while I get these logcat messages, and the service stops." The activity did not "die", any more than an activity is normally destroyed after pressing BACK or after being out of the foreground for a while.

Comment: So I'm a bit confused. The user starts my application, and with that my Service. The user is fully aware that the Service is running, as there is a notification, and the user gets notificated by that notification every couple of minutes, as the Service found some new data. This service needs to keep running until the user says 'I don't need anymore', and he can turn it off in my activity. -- So if this is the case, and I have called startForeground, I don't understand why my service crashes in under a half an hour after my Activity is closed. (As you said in other thread, your app takes days).

Comment: @Niek - My activity crashed quickly when I didn't handle the fact that it was put in landscape mode, so, you may want to look at that.  I haven't put the new version on my phone to see how it functions yet, but in the emulator it appears fixed. I also have it running as a remote service though.